# Can't Add grails gwt plugin to grails 2.4

Tags: grails, gwt, grails-plugin

When I am modifying the BuildConfig.groovy and add plugin using `compile ":org.grails.plugins:gwt:1.0.3"` then update grails dependencies I got following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad artifact coordinates
>   :org.grails.plugins:gwt:1.0.3

Any help regarding to this.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://github.com/simplicityitself/grails-gwt#installation) recommend:

```
build ":extended-dependency-manager:0.5.5"
compile ":gwt:1.0.3", {
    transitive=false
}
```

Also you need to specify gwt version in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
gwt {
    version="2.8.0"
}
```

And it requires resources plugin:

```
runtime "org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.14"
```